# Displaying IMG from data in panel created with HTML Services

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a sidepanel, its code get data uri image from server (specifically from a Google Docs, by using google.script.run).

I need to display it, I'm trying to do so on an IMG tag in the HTML document, but the sandbox forbid to assign anything to img.src .

Any ideas, instead of using templates?  Because I want to change the image dynamically.

Thank you

Comment: Are you using IFRAME sandbox? The image is hosted inside a Docs, the Drive or on an external server?

Comment: I'm not choosing any particular sandbox, I'm using the default one, which I believe is iframe sandbox.  The image is inside a Doc, I get the blob, convert to base64 and "return" it to the client panel.

Comment: Default SANDBOX is Native, it specifies it in the 3rd paragraph of the [ENUM Sandbox help documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/sandbox-mode), change to IFRAME and you should be fine.

Comment: I'm trying iframe sandbox, seems to work.  "Seems", because I'm having other errors, not related with this issue.  Thank you very much.  Do you want to answer the question, or should I?

Comment: Agora eu vejo que você é de Londrina.  Para que estamos falando em ingles? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are working inHtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME mode you can pass the base64 to the image src. Below is an example of using a template to do this.

code.gs

```
function doGet() {
   var t = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('index');
   t.icon = icon;
   return t.evaluate().setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
}
```

index.html

```
<div>
 <img src="data:image/png;base64,<?=icon?>"/>
</div>
```

icons.gs

```
var icon = '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';
```